# How to pass the user value for the size of an array into a function implemented in another code file?

Tags: arrays, c

I have no idea what to do. Whenever I try to insert `read_num[size]` it does not work. My debugger shows the value as 0. I want to take a value for the size of the array from the user. Then I want to use the value in another file.

So what I want to do is, I will do a printf to ask the user to give a value so that I can pass it as the size of the array. I did and it didn't work. Then I decided to write a direct value [36]. But I want user to insert 36.

This is what I have tried:

main.c

```
int main(void)
{
    int numbers[ARR_SIZE] = { 0 };
    int size = 36; // I am doing directly but I want to take the value from the user but it just does not work. 
    double mean = 0;
    double stddev = 0;
   
    read_array(size);
}
```

file.c

```
int read_array(int a[36]) //placing 36 directly, I want it to be placed by the user
{
    int num_read[36]; int i = 0; // I have no clue whats i am doing. I just want to pass the value  from the user. 
    while (i < a)
    {
   
        printf("Enter number");
        scanf_s("%d", &num_read[i]);
        ++i; 
     
    }
}
```

header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 100
int read_array(int arr[ARR_SIZE]);
double calc_mean(int arr[], int size);
double calc_stddev(int arr[], int size);
void print_array(int arr[], int size);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "I want to take the value from the user but it just does not work." How did you try to do so and in what way did it "just not work"?

Comment: You declare the correct arguments for all functions *except* the `read_array` function. How come?

Comment: And when you call `read_array`, why do you pass the `int` value of `size`, instead of the array `numbers`?

Comment: Also, if you include the header file in `main.c` then the compiler should have given you a warning in the call to `read_array`. Treats such warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: Please proviede a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you want to do with the array (and confirming my guess). But that changed the question after you got the initial version answered. That invalidates the given answer (admittedly mine). Please ask that different question separatly. I recommend to provide a [mre] of what you want to do in the shape of a single `main()`. I.e. do not split into functions and do not split into two separate code files. I assume that is what you can do or already did. Show that and the refactoring for multple code files can be what the answers there help you with.

Comment: Note: `int read_array(int a[36])` is _exactly_ same as `int read_array(int *a)`. This is a common misunderstanding of novice C programmers. Please use the latter syntax to avoid getting confused. The 36 is meaningless in C. If you want to mention it, write a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In you main.c file you want to decide the value of `size` and use that value in a call to the function `read_array()`.
You do so by calling `read_array(size);`, which makes sense to me.

Sadly your shown code lacks the details of whether or not you include your header file (and others). I assume that it does.

However, if what you are doing inside `main()` is actually what you want to do (I assume so), then the header file and the implementation of `read_array()` does not match that intention.

This `int read_array(int arr[ARR_SIZE])`, in your header and your implementation, means
"Dear compiler, this function takes an array (or a pointer to 100 consecutive `int`s)."

That does not match your plan of "I will give a single int as the parameter to the function."
To match that plan, use a prototype of `int read_array(int a);`.
The implementation code as shown should then work.

If you want the local array to actually be of the size given by the user and arriving via the parameter `a`, then change
`int num_read[36];` to `int num_read[a];`.

However, I suspect that you then intend to return the array which you filled with input from the user.
That is neither possible with a prototype of `int read_array(int a);` nor with one of `int read_array(int arr[ARR_SIZE]);`. Both mean "This function will return a single `int`.".
I assume you will need help with that, but you need to ask a separate question on how to return a new array from a C function - or better first search StackOverflow for a duplicate.

Comment: You almost give most of answers. I want to use the array value in different function. I want the user to insert 36. So I need to learn how to duplicate array?

Comment: I would not phrase as "duplicate". I think I know what you want to do, but I will not answer here and not based on guessing. Please create a separate question on what to do with the local array once you created and filled it based on the user-input size.

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please check now? I cant do any operation due to that. I must need to insert 36 from user not me.

Comment: " I must need to insert 36 from user not me." is what this answer covers. The other aspects of what you want you have added on top of the initial version of the question after you got my answer.

Comment: yeah. I thought of become more specific so that other can know what I am saying. You made me realize that I should post fully so I edited it again

Comment: The answer is probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495845/returning-array-from-function-in-c Make sure that your question does not get closed as a duplicate of that.

Comment: By the way, I do not see your edit to the question. And please consider making a new question before you edit this one again into a different one than I answered. I would have to delete the answer I spent time on to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. To pass the size of the array to the function (it does not matter if it is defined in the same or another compilation units) you need to have an additional parameter to the function. There is no other way of doing it in C language

```
int *doSomethingWithArray(int *array, size_t size)
{
    /* ... */    
}
```

> But I want user to insert 36.

The user can only enter something using I/O functions and has no access to the C code.

```
int *initArray(int *array, const size_t size)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index ++)
        array[index] = rand();
    return array;
}

int *printArray(int *array, const size_t size)
{
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index ++)
        printf("array[%3zu] = %d\n", index, array[index]);
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t array_size;

    srand(time(NULL));
    if(scanf("%zu", &array_size) == 1)  // user enters the size of the array
    {
        int array[array_size];

        initArray(array, array_size);
        printArray(array, array_size);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xjh9qGcrz

Comment: I worry that you are setting yourself up for being ignored or being hit by a moving target question. Good luck.